# how to find duplicate dropdowns in a table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a table which contains an user dropdown per row. Needs to prevent to select duplicate users in the table.

I have written js function for it.But it's not accomplish the requirements.

HTML
[image]

Javascript function

```
function  checkDuplicateUserId(obj){
  var user_id=$("#"+obj.id+" option:selected").val();            
  $('tbody#data tr select').each(function (i, row) {
  if ($('tbody#data tr select').find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').size() > 1) {
      alert();
  } 

  });

}

    function  checkAlreadySelected(obj){
        checkDuplicateUserId(obj);
        var num = parseInt($(obj).attr('num'));
        var user_id=$("#"+obj.id+" option:selected").val();            
        var next_user_id=$("#user_id_"+eval(num+1)+" option:selected").val();          
        if(user_id && typeof next_user_id == 'undefined'){
            var row = updateSrNo(num);
            $("#data").append(row);
        }

    }
```

Why this alert() not prompted while i choose the duplicate user from the table?

Comment: When or where this is called checkDuplicateUserId ?

Comment: It's called in checkAlreadySelected(obj) which is called in select 
onchange='return checkAlreadySelected(this);'

Comment: please see the edited description of question now.